# All of the month columns are printing "January" for some unknown reason

Tags: python, pandas

When I tried adding a "MONTH" column to make it easier to read the data, it resulted in everything being printed as "January"
Year: 2003 (STATUS)

```
STATUS                         Cancelled  Resolved  Shipped    MONTH
MONTH_ID                                                            
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001          0         0       39  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002          0         0       41  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003          0         0       50  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004          0         0       58  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005          0         0       58  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000006          0         0       46  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000007          0         0       50  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000008          0         0       58  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000009          0         0       76  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000010         16         8      134  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000011          0         0      296  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000012          0         0       70  January
```

This is what I want the result to look like:

```
STATUS                         Cancelled  Resolved  Shipped    MONTH
MONTH_ID                                                            
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001          0         0       39  January
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002          0         0       41  February
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003          0         0       50  March
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004          0         0       58  April
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005          0         0       58  May
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000006          0         0       46  June
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000007          0         0       50  July
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000008          0         0       58  August
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000009          0         0       76  September
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000010         16         8      134  October
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000011          0         0      296  November
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000012          0         0       70  December
```

Using `print(retail_data.head())`, this is what I got:

```
       ORDERNUMBER  QUANTITYORDERED  PRICEEACH  ORDERLINENUMBER    SALES  \
    0        10107               30      95.70                2  2871.00   
    1        10121               34      81.35                5  2765.90   
    2        10134               41      94.74                2  3884.34   
    3        10145               45      83.26                6  3746.70   
    4        10159               49     100.00               14  5205.27   
    
             ORDERDATE   STATUS  QTR_ID                      MONTH_ID  YEAR_ID  \
    0   2/24/2003 0:00  Shipped       1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002     2003   
    1    5/7/2003 0:00  Shipped       2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005     2003   
    2    7/1/2003 0:00  Shipped       3 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000007     2003   
    3   8/25/2003 0:00  Shipped       3 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000008     2003   
    4  10/10/2003 0:00  Shipped       4 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000010     2003   

   PRODUCTLINE  MSRP PRODUCTCODE              CUSTOMERNAME             PHONE  \
0  Motorcycles    95    S10_1678         Land of Toys Inc.        2125557818   
1  Motorcycles    95    S10_1678        Reims Collectables        26.47.1555   
2  Motorcycles    95    S10_1678           Lyon Souveniers  +33 1 46 62 7555   
3  Motorcycles    95    S10_1678         Toys4GrownUps.com        6265557265   
4  Motorcycles    95    S10_1678  Corporate Gift Ideas Co.        6505551386   

                    ADDRESSLINE1 ADDRESSLINE2           CITY STATE POSTALCODE  \
0        897 Long Airport Avenue          NaN            NYC    NY      10022   
1             59 rue de l'Abbaye          NaN          Reims   NaN      51100   
2  27 rue du Colonel Pierre Avia          NaN          Paris   NaN      75508   
3             78934 Hillside Dr.          NaN       Pasadena    CA      90003   
4                7734 Strong St.          NaN  San Francisco    CA        NaN   

  COUNTRY TERRITORY CONTACTLASTNAME CONTACTFIRSTNAME DEALSIZE  
0     USA       NaN              Yu             Kwai    Small  
1  France      EMEA         Henriot             Paul    Small  
2  France      EMEA        Da Cunha           Daniel   Medium  
3     USA       NaN           Young            Julie   Medium  
4     USA       NaN           Brown            Julie   Medium
```

This is the code I used:

```
retail_data['MONTH_ID'] = pd.to_datetime(retail_data['MONTH_ID'], errors='coerce')
yearly_status_dataframes = {}

for year in retail_data['YEAR_ID'].unique():
    year_data = retail_data[retail_data['YEAR_ID'] == year]
    aggregated_STATUS = year_data.groupby(['MONTH_ID', 'STATUS']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
    aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'] = aggregated_STATUS.index.month
    month_mapping = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
    aggregated_STATUS['MONTH'] = aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'].map(month_mapping)
    aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.sort_values(by='MONTH_NUMERIC')
    aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.drop(columns=['MONTH_NUMERIC'])
    yearly_status_dataframes[year] = aggregated_STATUS

for year, dataframe in yearly_status_dataframes.items():
    print(f"\nYear: {year} (STATUS)")
    print(dataframe)
```

I tried to add a 0 at the start, like this:

It worked for this code:

```
retail_data['MONTH_ID'] = pd.to_datetime(retail_data['MONTH_ID'], errors='coerce')
yearly_dataframes = {}

for year in retail_data['YEAR_ID'].unique():
    year_data = retail_data[retail_data['YEAR_ID'] == year]
    aggregated_sales = year_data.groupby('MONTH_ID')['SALES'].sum().reset_index()
    month_mapping = {'01': 'January', '02': 'February', '03': 'March', '04': 'April', '05': 'May', '06': 'June', '07': 'July', '08': 'August', '09': 'September', '10': 'October', '11': 'November', '12': 'December'}
    aggregated_sales['MONTH'] = aggregated_sales['MONTH_ID'].astype(str).str[-2:].map(month_mapping)
    aggregated_sales = aggregated_sales.sort_values(by='SALES', ascending=False)
    yearly_dataframes[year] = aggregated_sales

for year, dataframe in yearly_dataframes.items():
    print(f"\nYear: {year}")
    print(dataframe)
```

However for the other code it printed NaN variables for the month instead, I don't know why this happens. You could just say to re-use the first code, but that isn't an option as it becomes so unorganized. Here is an example:

```
 MONTH_ID STATUS MONTH 
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002 ShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShipped 
February 7 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000008 
 ShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShippedShipped 
August 11 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000012
```

How can I fix the month column to display the correct month?

Edit: I tried turning it into a list first, then splicing it. It resulted into a ValueError: Length of values (12) does not match length of index (5)
By the way, this is the updated code I used for that:

```
# Convert 'MONTH_ID' to datetime if it's not already in the datetime format
retail_data['MONTH_ID'] = pd.to_datetime(retail_data['MONTH_ID'], errors='coerce')

month_retail_data = retail_data['MONTH_ID'].values.tolist()
month_mapping = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
month_retail_data_names = [month_mapping[month] for month in month_retail_data]

# Extract unique months from the grouped data
unique_months = month_retail_data[:12]

# Create an empty dictionary to store DataFrames for each year (STATUS)
yearly_status_dataframes = {}

# Iterate over unique years and create DataFrames (STATUS)
for year in retail_data['YEAR_ID'].unique():
    # Filter data for the current year
    year_data = retail_data[retail_data['YEAR_ID'] == year]

    # Group by 'MONTH_ID' and count the occurrences of each 'STATUS' value for each group
    aggregated_STATUS = year_data.groupby(['MONTH_ID', 'STATUS']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

    # Extract the month part from 'MONTH_ID' as a numeric value
    aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'] = [month_mapping[month] for month in unique_months]

    # Create a mapping dictionary for the numeric month values to month names
    month_mapping = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}

    # Create the 'MONTH' column by mapping the numeric values to month names
    aggregated_STATUS['MONTH'] = aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'].map(month_mapping)

    # Sort the DataFrame by 'MONTH_NUMERIC' in ascending order
    aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.sort_values(by='MONTH_NUMERIC')

    # Drop the 'MONTH_NUMERIC' column after sorting
    aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.drop(columns=['MONTH_NUMERIC'])

    # Store the DataFrame for the current year in the dictionary (STATUS)
    yearly_status_dataframes[year] = aggregated_STATUS

# Display the DataFrames for each year (STATUS)
for year, dataframe in yearly_status_dataframes.items():
    print(f"\nYear: {year} (STATUS)")
    print(dataframe)
```

Yes, I tried splicing the list, and got the same ValueError, it just so happened that the numbers got flipped in the ValueError

Second edit: so I tried using Teemu Risikko's answer, and it got somewhere

```
month_retail_data = retail_data['MONTH_ID'].values.tolist()
month_mapping = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}
month_retail_data_names = [month_mapping[month] for month in month_retail_data]
print(month_retail_data)
print(month_retail_data_names)

# Convert 'MONTH_ID' to datetime if it's not already in the datetime format
retail_data["MONTH_ID"].apply(lambda m: calendar.month_name[m])

# Group by 'MONTH_ID' and count the occurrences of each 'STATUS' value for each group
aggregated_STATUS = retail_data.groupby(['MONTH_ID', 'STATUS']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

# Extract the month part from 'MONTH_ID' as a numeric value
aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'] = month_retail_data[:12]

# Create a mapping dictionary for the numeric month values to month names
month_mapping = {1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March', 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June', 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September', 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'}

# Create the 'MONTH' column by mapping the numeric values to month names
aggregated_STATUS['MONTH'] = aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'].map(month_mapping)[:12]

# Sort the DataFrame by 'MONTH_NUMERIC' in ascending order
aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.sort_values(by='MONTH_NUMERIC')

# Drop the 'MONTH_NUMERIC' column after sorting
aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.drop(columns=['MONTH_NUMERIC'])

# Display the sorted aggregated STATUS DataFrame
print("\nAggregated STATUS:")
print(aggregated_STATUS)
```

(if you're wondering about the commented code that's where I tried using Teemo Risikko's answer, but it works with nanosecond precision)
However, it still prints the months in the wrong order:

```
Aggregated STATUS:
STATUS    Cancelled  Disputed  In Process  On Hold  Resolved  Shipped  \
MONTH_ID                                                                
10               16         0           0        0         8      293   
1                 0         0           0        0        13      216   
11                0         0           0        6         8      583   
12                0         0           0        0         0      180   
2                 0         0           0        0         0      224   
3                 0         0           0        0        18      194   
4                 0         3           0       24         0      151   
5                14        11          41       14         0      172   
6                30         0           0        0         0      101   
7                 0         0           0        0         0      141   
8                 0         0           0        0         0      191   
9                 0         0           0        0         0      171   

STATUS       MONTH  
MONTH_ID            
10         January  
1         February  
11        February  
12           April  
2              May  
3             July  
4           August  
5          October  
6          October  
7         November  
8         November  
9         December
```

If you are reading this, please let me know what I implemented wrong. Many thanks!

Edit 3:
So I decided to print aggregated_STATUS['MONTH_NUMERIC'] and it turns out it jumbles everything:

```
MONTH_ID
1      6
2      8
3      9
4     11
5     11
6     12
7     12
8      1
9      2
10     3
11     5
12     6
Name: MONTH_NUMERIC, dtype: int64
```

If anyone knows how to fix it, it will be very much appreciated

Comment: If possible please share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current code, meaning that you show us some sample data as text, an expected output and as little code as possible to reproduce the actual issue. Currently it's hard to debug especially because we don't know what kind of data you have in your dataframe.

Comment: What parts of the code should I add aside from importing stuff to make it an MRE (btw the one that's too big for stack overflow is the output)

Comment: It's just that you don't show us what your input data looks like, so it's impossible to deduct from your code where it is going wrong when we don't know what is going in and what the end result should look like.

Comment: Stack Overflow won't let me add the data file though

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to add *some* of it as a text to the question. Just `print(retail_data.head())` or something so we can see a few lines of example data and the column structure.

Comment: Alright, just did that

Comment: What do you get if you remove `aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.drop(columns=['MONTH_NUMERIC'])`? Does the `MONTH_NUMERIC` column contain only 1's?

Comment: It looks like your "month" is just some nanoseconds into the first of January 1970(the start of UNIX time). I guess that's where the issue is located.

Comment: Update: I tried converting it into a list and got a ValueError, I added it in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so taking the relevant parts from your input data, here's an example where it goes wrong and how to fix it. I used this as a test input

```
retail_data = pd.DataFrame({
    "MONTH_ID": [2, 5, 7, 8, 10], 
    "YEAR_ID": [2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003], 
    "SALES": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})
```

### Solution 1:

You immediately go wrong in the beginning by trying to convert `MONTH_ID` to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`. You can't do this for month id only:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(retail_data["MONTH_ID"])
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005
...
```

Now then, to get the month id as a month name you can use for example [calendar API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name):

```
import calendar

>>> retail_data["MONTH_ID"].apply(lambda m: calendar.month_name[m])
0    February
1         May
2        July
```

### Solution 2

I see your input data also has a column `ORDERDATE`. In case that corresponds to the `MONTH_ID`, you can also do the following:

This time use `pd.to_datetime` combined with the `dt` accessor:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(retail_data["ORDERDATE"]).dt.month_name()
0    February
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming retail_data is loaded from a CSV file
retail_data = pd.read_csv("retail_data.csv")

# Convert MONTH_ID column to datetime
retail_data['MONTH_ID'] = pd.to_datetime(retail_data['MONTH_ID'], errors='coerce')

yearly_status_dataframes = {}

for year in retail_data['YEAR_ID'].unique():
    year_data = retail_data[retail_data['YEAR_ID'] == year]
    aggregated_STATUS = year_data.groupby(['MONTH_ID', 'STATUS']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
    aggregated_STATUS['MONTH'] = aggregated_STATUS.index.strftime('%B')
    aggregated_STATUS = aggregated_STATUS.sort_values(by='MONTH_ID')
    yearly_status_dataframes[year] = aggregated_STATUS

for year, dataframe in yearly_status_dataframes.items():
    print(f"\nYear: {year} (STATUS)")
    print(dataframe)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: That just fills the month column with "January"

Comment: @MigsBautista, got it. Please check updated solution

Comment: Ended up with the same result